# Email forwarding over windows and iis7

Tags: email, iis, iis-7, forwarding, mail-forwarding

I am trying to make a mail piping sytem work and I am having trouble as I am not used to working with IIS7 over Windows.

The [official documentation](http://docs.accord5.com/Email_Piping) talks about how to do it with Cpanel and X3 skin, but I have no idea if this can be done on IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with the (rather basic) SMTP service built into Windows.

Comment: Then, which solutions could be done over Windows? How windows servers deal with this stuff? Thanks.